# MOSFETs as amplifier

Tags: transistors, mosfet, amplifier, gain

I have used bipolar transistors as amplifiers but am having confusion regarding using MOSFETs as amplifiers. In the bipolar transistor case I use the simple formula of R2/R1 where R2 is the collector resistance while the R1 is the emitter resistance. Does that rule apply in the MOSFET case as well? Kindly suggest me an easy method of finding the gain and setting the offset.
[image]

Source: [amplifier](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/amp_2.html)

Comment: Are you referring to a common source amplifier with a degeneration resistor and resistor load? You could add a diagram showing the topology to your question to be clear.

Comment: You may wish to read through [this appendix](https://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/fdscontent/uscompanion/us/static/companion.websites/9780199339136/Appendices/Appendix_G.pdf). It provides some useful comparisons. (The MOSFET is a squared-law device and its gm won't compare to the BJT.)

Comment: Designing electronic devices without basic knowledge how the components work is senseless. BJT  controlled by current, FET is controlled by voltage, completely different.

Comment: @user263983 See the Shockley equation or Ebers-Moll model. BJTs are voltage controlled as well. They just require a recombination current to keep operating. Physics is physics. This is an old debate and there are points to be made for each side. But i wouldn't be so strident. And the BJT models are quite clear about the reality.

Comment: EEK21, forget this "tutorial" - it contains false information. At first, the ratio (-RL/RE) is a rough approximation and applies to large RE values only (RE>>1/gm). Here gm is the transconductance gm=Ic/Vt. This is the slope of the voltage-control characteristic Ic=f(Vbe). Secondly, there is no "small internal resistance built into its emitter region". Perhaps the author refers to the inverse transconductance which sometimes is named as re=1/gm. However, this is (a) not a resistance and (b) not "built into the emitter region" Such a view gives a wrong understanding how a BJT really works.

Comment: To illustrate my criticism, here are two contradictory statements from this "tutorial":
(1) "This method of biasing the transistor greatly reduces the effects of varying Beta, ( β ) by holding the Base bias at a constant steady voltage level allowing for best stability." Some sentences later we can read: (2) "a small change in the Base current will cause a large change in the Collector current."

Comment: @LvW Probably comes from [*"The Art of Electronics: Student Manual"* by Hayes and Horowitz, page 101](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifvqo.png).

Comment: @periblepsis But on the same page we can read: " This "resistance" we call "little re"; please note that it is not a resistor planted in the transistor; it only models the limited gain of the device".

Comment: @LvW Yes, I saw that. I'm not arguing with you at all. Just offering a hint about where that other picture might have come from. So it is just the picture is what I'm referring to. Lots of people look at pictures and may copy them from memory easily. Not everyone reads the text below or copies that with any fidelity. But I honestly don't know.

Comment: @periblepsis I agree with you. I must admit that I never have used equivalent circuit diagrams and - in particular - I do not like the T-schematic (with this "re"). It models the BJT in a manner which very often leads to misinterpretations. Even worse: It prevents the newcomer from developing a correct understanding of the BJT.

Comment: @LvW I can't tell you how many EE graduates I've encountered who have terribly wrong ideas about BJTs and how they work. One of them is a nephew-in-law. He had no idea. He's working as a programmer, now. Which is a good idea given the education he absorbed. ;)

Comment: @periblepsis Example: Microelectronic Circuit Design (R.C.Jaeger, McGraw-Hill): 
"The three terminal currents are all exponentially dependent on the base-emitter voltage". 
On the same page we also can read: "Because the current gain beta>>1, injection of a small current into the base of the transistor produces a much larger current in both the collector and the emitter terminals". 
(My comment: Note especially the word "produces"!)

Answer (score 0):

As far as the voltage gain is concerend, for both types (BJT and FET) we are using the same formula because both types are voltage-driven devices:

- Gain (without emitter/source degeneration): A=-gmRL (with RL=effective load resistor at the collector/drain node and gm=transconductance).
- Gain (with emitter/source degeneration): A=-gmRL/(1 + gmRF) (with feedback resistor RF in the emitter/source path). Approximation for RF>>1/gm:  A=-RL/RF.
- Emitter/source degeneration provides negative current-controlled voltage feedback.

Comment: So in both cases I can use the RL/RF for the gain right??

Comment: @EEK21 Only when RF>>1/gm (inverse transconductance). Otherwise the denominator contains the sum (RF + 1/gm)